Manhwa/manga about red/orange haired fl with green eyes who travels back in time to get revenge on her father and step sister
The female lead's mother dies. Her father had white hair with green eyes and her mother had orange or red hair. Her father had an affair with a white haired women and had a daughter with her. That step sister becomes the cause of her death. The female lead is somehow reincarnated back to where she was around 5-6, but remembers everything.
She had three marriages in her past life. In her current life, after the funeral of her mother, she goes back to live with her grandparents. She also had a son from one of her marriages, but her husband ran away somewhere with him (not sure about this son part).

I think you mean "revenge on her father and step-sister" rather than "his."
